# Symfony2: adding dynamically an element to a double embedded relation form

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, dynamic, double

One model like this:

```
class X
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Block", mappedBy="x",cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $block;
...

class Block
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="BlockA", mappedBy="block")
     */
    private $blockA;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="BlockB", mappedBy="block")
     */
    private $blockB;
...
class BlockA
{
...
```

I can dynamically add Blocks to X (collection) through Ajax in a XType form. It is saving correctly.

But what i cannot is to save a dynamically created BlockA nested in a Block. That always gives me a form validation error: "This form should not contain extra fields.".

The form validator admits "X" to dynamically adding "Block"s with new relations with "BlockA" or "BlockB". But just in a collection of "Block"s with all of them having relations with objectos of class "BlockA" or all of them having relations with elements of class "BlockB". It is imposible to validate a collection with some of the "Block"s having a "BlockA" relation and others having "BlockB" relation (validation error extra fields is shown).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you past the full exception?

Comment: Sorry it is not an exception but a form validation error: "This form should not contain extra fields."

Comment: Can you show us your form type?

Comment: The Block form type here: http://pastie.org/7696328

Comment: Can you show us `BlockAType()` and `BlockBType()` definitions?

Comment: Here BlockAType and BlockBType:  http://pastie.org/7702207

Comment: What if you remove `cascade_validation` from `BlockAType` and `BlockBType`?

Comment: I tried that but does not solve the problem. Even BlockB is a dynamic collection form that needs it.